# Google Keystone agent failing

Tags: google-chrome, launchd

Whenever I check out my `launchd` agents in [LaunchControl](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) I notice that has exited with `Error 1`. The agent is sent to run the following command every 3,623 seconds (!):

```
/Users/kuzzooroo/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode ifneeded
```

Here's what I get when I run the command manually:

```
$ /Users/kuzzooroo/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode ifneeded
2023-01-07 16:13:05.897 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[1884/0x16fc83000] [lvl=3] -[KSAdaptiveXPCDialer syncProcessDialResult:forAttempt:withError:] com.google.Keystone.system.AgentService + 1: connection test com.google.Keystone.system.AgentService/0: failure [com.google.Keystone.FallbackXPCErrorDomain:5 - 'KSAdaptiveXPCDialer.m:494'] (Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. [NSCocoaErrorDomain:4099])
```

Part of me thinks I should not care, but I do always hear about the importance of keeping software up-to-date to avoid security issues. Is Google Keystone still the way Google software stays up-to-date, and if so, how can I fix this error?

UPDATE: the error message is hard to read because I used code block formatting and the line doesn't wrap. Here as a more readable form: `2023-01-07 16:13:05.897 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[1884/0x16fc83000] [lvl=3] -[KSAdaptiveXPCDialer syncProcessDialResult:forAttempt:withError:] com.google.Keystone.system.AgentService + 1: connection test com.google.Keystone.system.AgentService/0: failure [com.google.Keystone.FallbackXPCErrorDomain:5 - 'KSAdaptiveXPCDialer.m:494'] (Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. [NSCocoaErrorDomain:4099])`